# Density grid plot rotated when given x and y values (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a grid density plot for a set of data points and when using matplotlib 2dhistogram to create a grid contour the resulting colour plot seems to be flipped in the vertical axis and rotated too. I can't see why this is the case but I have put my code below and will attach an image of the plots.

```
import numpy as np
from ngtsio import ngtsio
import math 
from statsmodels import robust
from numpy import mean, absolute
from astropy.stats import LombScargle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gridx = np.linspace(0,frac,21)
gridy = np.linspace(0,1,21)

grid,_,_ = np.histogram2d(new_phase,binned_flux,bins=[gridx,gridy])

plt.grid(True)
plt.pcolormesh(gridx,gridy,grid)
plt.colorbar()

plt.grid()
plt.plot(new_phase,binned_flux,'r.',linestyle='None',markersize = markersize)
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.xlim(0,frac)
plt.xlabel('Phase')
```

please note that `frac` is an array of (0.5,1.0,2.0) i.e. the limits seen in the 3 subplot x-axes and the code runs through each and plots in turn. [image]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: it turns out all I needed to do was change: grid,_,_ = np.histogram2d(new_phase,binned_flux,bins=[gridx,gridy])   to   grid,_,_ = np.histogram2d(binned_flux,new_phase,bins=[gridy,gridx])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is arising because `numpy.histogram2d` and `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh` interpret rows and columns inverted. You can see this with a very simple example, e.g. producing and then plotting a histogram of a single point at (0.75, 0.25) with bins of 0.0-0.5 and 0.5-1.0 in both directions:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.asarray([0.75])
y = np.asarray([0.25])
bin_edges = np.asarray([0.0, 0.5, 1.0])  # called gridx/gridy above
hist,_,_ = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=[bin_edges, bin_edges]) 
                                         # called grid above
print(hist)
# array([[ 0.,  0.],
#        [ 1.,  0.]])
plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")
plt.pcolormesh(bin_edges, bin_edges, hist)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

gives:

[image]

While `histogram2d` interprets row-indices as x-direction and column-indices as y-direction (meaning that columns share an x-value and rows share an y-value), the inverse is true for `pcolormesh`. To get the correct behavior you can change the plot command to:

```
plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")
plt.pcolormesh(bin_edges, bin_edges, hist.T)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you! A very well presented and easily understandable answer too by the way